# I want to replace this forEach function with the same but done using reduce. Can you say where I am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I create the columns and I have a checkbox which shows the columns name. When I click a checkbox square I get an array of checked names which are stored in `checkedKeys`. Now `checkableColumns` contains all the possible checkable values.
Those elements which are in checkableColumns but not in checkedKeys are those columns that will disappear from the table's columns.
I don't filter from all columns because some columns should always be visible.
This is common part to reduce and forEach:

```
const columns = initColumns();
        const checkableColumns = ["n", "yi", "ui", "r", "t"];
        const notCheckedValues = checkableColumns.filter(col=>!checkedKeys.includes(col));
        const filteredColumns =[];
```

Here how I solved with forEach:

```
columns.forEach(column=>{
      if(!notCheckedValues.includes(column.dataIndex)){
            filteredColumns.push(column);
          }
    })
```

Here how I tried to solve with reduce, but it doesn't work and I didn't understand:

```
const filteredColumns = columns.reduce((allColumns, currentColumn)=>{
      if(notCheckedValues.includes(currentColumn.dataIndex)){
        return allColumns;
      }
      console.log("all cols",allColumns, "push",allColumns.push(currentColumn))
      return allColumns.push(currentColumn)
    }, [])
```

Comment: Why `.forEach()` or `.reduce()`? That's a job for `.filter()`

Comment: Apart from the major thing mentioned in the answer, you are pushing twice, once in the `log`, once in the `return`.

Comment: _"but it doesn't work"_ - is an absolute useless information ;) Instead describe the behavior, what's wrong with that and in this case post the error from the console.

Comment: Your approach would work if you used `.concat()` instead of `.push()`. `.push()` mutates the array while `.concat()` keeps the original array unmodified and instead returns a new array containing all the elements of the original array plus those provided to the method, which seems to be what you expect in your code. So: `return allColumns.concat(currentColumn)`. I mention this as a complementary FYI to the answer you've already been provided with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.push` does not return the Array, but the new length of the array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Instead, you would need to return the accumulator *after* pushing:

```js
const filteredColumns = columns.reduce((allColumns, currentColumn) => {
  if (notCheckedValues.includes(currentColumn.dataIndex)) {
    return allColumns;
  }
  allColumns.push(currentColumn)
  return allColumns
}, [])
```

---

You could however also do this in a more idiomatic way by using `Array.prototype.filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
const filteredColumns = columns.filter((currentColumn) => {
  return !notCheckedValues.includes(currentColumn.dataIndex)
})
```

Comment: Why `+ 1` in the push?